# Save Word document as PDF, how to prevent creation of hyperlinks in PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, hyperlink

It seems that a Word document that contains some text that looks like an email address (e.g., joe@example.com) but that is intentionally NOT marked as a hyperlink, is turned into a hyperlink in the resulting PDF when saving as a PDF.

How can I save a Word document (using Word 2007) as a PDF and *prevent* any hyperlinks to be created?

(I am pretty sure that it is a hyperlink *encoded* in the PDF. As when opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat 8.0, SumatraPDF or Google Chrome, all three viewers indicate a hyperlink when hoovering over the relevant email address)

Note - again - that they are never marked or shown as a (blue, underlined) hyperlink in the Word document itself. Only in the PDF they become clickable when you hover over them.

Comment: Rather than closing this question, answer it yourself so future visitors can reference it if they have the same question.

Comment: @Rabarberski - Please remove the "answer" from your question and post the contents of the "answer" as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, seems I was wrong and that no link is created. In Acrobat's monstrous preferences menu, I just found on option under 'General' that says 'Create links form URLs'.

When unchecking it, there is no more link when hoovering.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is having this issue **in Word 2013 with images, when saving as PDF**...  I ran across this when looking for an answer to my embedded images displaying URL's to their original location when the document is converted to PDF.  e.g. hovering over a picture displayed a non-clickable URL of, e.g. \NAS01\Photos\Repository\Etc.

When you save the file as PDF, click the **Options** button when you're selecting the destination directory and filename.  Uncheck the **Document structure tags for accessibility** checkblock.

That worked for me.  I did not have to update anything in the document itself, but, I do have to disable this checkblock every time I save the document as a PDF (the setting isn't persistent).

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Select Word's `Tools` | `AutoCorrect Options...` menu item and on the AutoFormat tab in the dialog box, disable `Internet and network paths with hyperlinks` in the `Replace` section. If there are already some in the file, you'll have to manually remove them.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Note that the problem is not that they are turned into blue/underlined hyperlinks in Word itself (they aren't). Only in the PDF they apparently are marked as a mailto: link.

Comment: Wish you had clarified that in your question...as well as mentioned you were using Acrobat, because if you had I would have told you to change its `Create links from URLs` General Preference.